# PhantomJS 2.1.1 (Mac OS X 0.0.0) ERROR SyntaxError: Invalid character: '#'

Tags: angularjs, phantomjs, karma-runner, karma-jasmine

i'm new in testing a angular test so i need hand for a professional out there

i use karma, jasmine and phantomjs i just follow the video tuts

so i finish the config and i try my test

here my karma congif

```
// Karma configuration
// Generated on Fri Feb 24 2017 09:59:10 GMT+0800 (PHT)

module.exports = function(config) {
config.set({

// base path that will be used to resolve all patterns (eg. files, exclude)
basePath: '',


// frameworks to use
// available frameworks: https://npmjs.org/browse/keyword/karma-adapter
frameworks: ['jasmine'],


// list of files / patterns to load in the browser
files: [
    '../../bower_components/angular/angular.js',
    '../../bower_components/angular-mocks/angular-mocks.js',
    '../app/caes/controllers/positions/PositionIndexCtrl.coffee',
    'unit/*.js'
],


// list of files to exclude
exclude: [
],


// preprocess matching files before serving them to the browser
// available preprocessors: https://npmjs.org/browse/keyword/karma-preprocessor
preprocessors: {
},


// test results reporter to use
// possible values: 'dots', 'progress'
// available reporters: https://npmjs.org/browse/keyword/karma-reporter
reporters: ['progress'],


// web server port
port: 9876,


// enable / disable colors in the output (reporters and logs)
colors: true,


// level of logging
// possible values: config.LOG_DISABLE || config.LOG_ERROR || config.LOG_WARN || config.LOG_INFO || config.LOG_DEBUG
logLevel: config.LOG_INFO,


// enable / disable watching file and executing tests whenever any file changes
autoWatch: true,


// start these browsers
// available browser launchers: https://npmjs.org/browse/keyword/karma-launcher
browsers: ['PhantomJS'],


// Continuous Integration mode
// if true, Karma captures browsers, runs the tests and exits
singleRun: false,

// Concurrency level
// how many browser should be started simultaneous
concurrency: Infinity
})
}
```

my unit test testingPositionCtrlSpec.js

```
describe('Testing Position Suite', function () {
describe('Testing Position Controller',function () {

    it('Should initialize the position in the scope ', function () {
        module('CaesApp');

        var scope = {};
        var ctrl;
        inject(function ($controller) {
            ctrl = $controller('PositionIndexCtrl', {$scope:scope})
        });

        expect($scope.position).toBeDefine();

    });
  });
 });
```

this is the controller i test PositionIndexCtrl.coffee

```
#= require ./../../module

PositionIndexCtrl = ($scope, $resource, $route, $mdDialog, Position)->


@positions = Position::list.query()


@showNew = (ev)->
  position = new Position()
  $mdDialog.show
   controller: "PositionNewDialogCtrl"
   templateUrl: '/templates/positions/new'
   parent: angular.element(document.body)
   targetEvent: ev
   clickOutsideToClose:true
   fullscreen: @customFullscreen
   locals:
     position: position

$scope.edit = (rowId) ->
  position = Position.get(id: rowId)
  $mdDialog.show
    controller: "PositionEditDialogCtrl"
    templateUrl: '/templates/positions/edit'
    parent: angular.element(document.body)
    clickOutsideToClose:true
    fullscreen: @customFullscreen
    locals:
      position: position

$scope.delete = (rowId) ->
  Position.get { id: rowId }, (position) ->
    confirm = $mdDialog.confirm().title('Would you like to delete '+      position.name + ' Position').targetEvent(rowId).ok('Yes!').cancel('Cancel')
  $mdDialog.show(confirm).then (->
    position.$remove ->
      console.log('Deleted Success!')
      $route.reload()
  )
return


PositionIndexCtrl.$inject = ["$scope", "$resource", "$route", "$mdDialog", "Position"]

angular 
.module "CaesApp"
.controller "PositionIndexCtrl", PositionIndexCtrl
```

my error in terminal

> PhantomJS 2.1.1 (Mac OS X 0.0.0) ERROR
>     SyntaxError: Invalid character: '#'
>     at /Users/cdasia-tsd/Desktop/revampCAES/app/assets/javascripts/app/caes/controllers/positions/PositionIndexCtrl.coffee:1

i dont know why he consider '#' a error?

my hypothesis

- he cant read coffeescript??
- i need to declare #require to my unit test?

if someone experience this please share your knowledge

Answer (score 1):

You have to compile your coffescript into JavaScript before karma can run it. Karma can't run coffescript, nothing runs coffescript directly, it's always compiled into JavaScript.

You can use https://github.com/karma-runner/karma-coffee-preprocessor

Comment: i will try this solution i'm new in testing and config so it will really hard for me

Comment: still the same bro

Comment: This comment doesn't tell us anything about what you tried, what the error was, how can we possibly help?